# Upgrading to PHP 7.2 causes 500 Error

Tags: joomla-3.x, php7, linux

I currently have a Joomla 3.8.7 running on a Xubuntu 14.04 LAMP server. The site was working normally until the server was upgraded to PHP 7.2. Now when we try to access the admin login or the site we receive a 500 error. There are no errors in the apache2 log file. I have updated the php.ini file with recommended settings and still the 500 error.

I also tried renaming the .htaccess file as a long shot attempt but it did not help so I renamed it back.

I created a generic info.php with phpinfo() and it shows PHP 7.2 from the browser. The command line php -v also shows PHP 7.2.

In order to get the site back I a2dismod php7.2, a2enmod php5.6, and then restarted apache2. It is working as before but we still need to get to 7.2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What 3rd party extensions do you have?  My guess is your have a plugin or something that is having issues and that is causing the error.  Make sure error reporting is set to E_ALL (check in phpinfo.php) so it catches depreciated errors as well.